# Let's raise some bounty for well-written Q&As

Tags: discussion, bounty

I have increasingly become occupied by matters which have taken a hit on my overall contribution to help increase the quality content on our site. While I'm greatly thankful to everyone who has been contributing here regardless of the question quality issues, I still want to do something better on my part (besides doing my job as a moderator).

Some moons ago I started raising bounty on answers and questions which I believe are highly insightful to the matter they dealt with.  In my humble opinion, I believe this is one of the good ways to not only appreciate good content materially, but also encourage a contributor to remain engaged with our site, and bring more useful, insightful and quality content in time.

I well very understand that reputation points should not be the primary aim of a person to contribute here (as that may lure them towards acts which could invite disciplinary action on their accounts), but I also know that the +X green notification in the top bar does feel rewarding and encouraging at times.

With this in mind, I invite all the members of our community to share posts, be they answers or questions, which they believe are worthy of appreciation.

---

## Criteria for post selection

Here's the criteria that you *may use* to judge the content of an answer:

- the content cannot easily be found or compiled from the internet;
- the content proved *significant* to help increase your knowledge base or skill set;
- the content deals more with fundamentals of a concept, and hacks, instead of merely mentioning some X program's usage;
- the content to your satisfaction answers the question.

And here's the criteria that you *may use* to judge the content of a question:

- the issue cannot easily be solved by doing web search (including advanced Google search);
- the issue pertains to a problem with the OS (even if OEM skin specific) or a concept, than just being with an app;
- the asker has attempted to at least exhaust options to address their problem themselves;
- when the above criteria are met and the asker has significantly low reputation points to raise a bounty on their own;

---

## How to share a post?

**One post One suggestion**

For answer posts, post an answer below like this prefixed by ###:

> #### Bounty proposal for the [Answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/28315) to [How to fully backup non-rooted devices?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28296)

For question posts, simply link the question encapsulated by its heading prefixed by ### like this:

> #### Bounty proposal for the Question: [How to fully backup non-rooted devices?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/28315)

You are free to mention the name of the contributor and why you believe a bounty should be considered by community members for that post.

**Note:** when a bounty has been successfully awarded, please edit the relevant answer post below and highlight at the top "Bounty awarded" followed, *optionally*, by the bounty issuer's name.

---

## When to award a bounty?

Being a free (as in freedom) member you can give bounty to any post you deem fit at anytime (subjected to rules of Stack Exchange). The answers below are only meant to bring to our *"attention"* the content (and the contributors) as a centralized repository of content we value.

---

## Notes

- given that our consistent answer contributors are a handful in strength, multiple posts from a contributor are eligible. Furthermore, a contributor is free to suggest their own answers (not questions) if they believe their answer meets the criteria.
- I personally want to focus more on users who are sub-2k and sub-3k reputation because those are the checkpoints that grants rights to engage more on the moderation side and feel genuinely as being an important part of the functioning of the site without necessarily relying on the moderators, as is the case with flagging.
- this whole idea stands upon voluntary contribution, so there shall be no moral mandate on any user, regardless of their reputation and moderation rights, to raise a bounty.

Comment: Good initiative, will encourage community members to focus more on sharing knowledge than just asking for or giving tips and tricks. And though at the moment they don't seem to pay much heed to your proposal, you yourself have been doing it very well, in my opinion. Appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

**Status**: Bounty awarded, on Sept 5, 2019.

---

#### Bounty proposal for the [Answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/204765/3573) to [How to export a list as Text of all Play Store Apps that I have ever installed](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/204752/3573)

The closest topics I can find is [How can I export a list of currently installed applications to a file?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/9824/3573) which covers existing apps on device, and you still need the device to be useful, or depend on an ever changing [Play Store website](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/49694/3573). A online search bringing up non-StackExchange site show similar results.

The prior usage of Google Takeout was for [GDPR data removal](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/196694/3573) or [Contact extraction](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/189118/3573), so the usage of Google Takeout for App list extraction is at least novel.

Answer (score 2):

**Status**: Bounty awarded on 18 Nov 19 by user beeshyams

---

#### Bounty proposal for the [Answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218469/96277) to [How to stop apps writing to “Android” folder on the SD card?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/214288/96277)

**Reason**: user Irfan's answer is well researched and comprehensive. It deserves recognition.

In addition, it gives a good top level view and in depth treatment thus suitable for casual and serious enthusiasts.

Answer (score 1):

**Status:** Bounty awarded on 05/01/20 by beeshyams

---

**Bounty** for the **[answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219884/131553)** to **[SELinux permissive kernel - is it a security risk?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/219821/131553)**

**Reason:** Thanks Irfan for demystifying and helping me take an informed decision. I ended up flashing SELinux permissive kernel with the device having SELinux Enforcing